# Highcharts drilldown set x-axis setExtremes

Tags: highcharts

I have highcharts with 3 layers drilldown.
I want to put the auto scroll on only second level of drill down, not else in other layets.

My fiddle is : https://jsfiddle.net/ofam6c04/

```
      events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {
                var chart = this;
                    counter = 0;
                    range = 9;
                    max = 0;
                    clearInterval(interval);

                    equ_counter++;
                    console.log('drilldown', equ_counter);
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(counter, range);
                    }, 200);


                    if (equ_counter == 1) {
                        max = e.point.sites;
                        console.log('max', max);

                        interval = setInterval(function () {
                            console.log('counter', counter);
                            if (counter >= (max - d_range)) {
                                if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                                    counter = 0;
                                    range = 9;
                                } else {
                                    counter = 1;
                                    range = 10;
                                }
                            }
                            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(counter, range);
                            counter++;
                            range++;
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                },
```

I have some problems mentioned as below.

1. After go to 2nd layer, some unwanted 0 (Zeroes) show sometimes.
2. Suppose, I have 57 sites in layer-2, I want to move into 10's group (Each time 10 sites rotates) and suppose at last rotation, if 7 sites are remaining, only 7 bars need to show.
3. After complete 57 sites rotation, redirect auto from 1st site.

- Note: all should be done in only layer-2. If I go to layer-3 or layer-1, no rotation is needed. and again go to layer-2, counts starts from first or last stage again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like a regression, I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15663

As a workaround you can use the previous version of Highcharts, if you doesn't need the newest features:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/7/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/7/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bqvexo92/

---

Or render this chart using data labels instead of stack labels:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        borderColor: 'none',
        grouping: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#3D3D3D',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                textOutline: false,
                fontSize: '12px'
            },
        }
    }
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nwsbom5z/

---

2. Here is my idea of how to implement this kind of carousel:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/62u0rf5e/